# Automatically integrate email string into Trello

Tags: trello, email

We use Trello for customer relationship management - to see all leads and sales pipeline.

Is it possible to integrate natively in Trello the facility automatically to input any email correspondence from a lead into a Trello card string, so along with other notes all of their email data would come in also?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the Email-to-board settings?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise i have but as far as i could see it allows you to create a new card from an email, rather than update an existing card with content from an email, is that correct or are there more features / options to it

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise just had  a look at the docs and it seems you can email to the card, what ill do is setup a rule in our email client that if we get an incoming or send an outgoing email to X address cc the relevant card. - http://help.trello.com/article/809-creating-cards-by-email